getting error Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'
I am using below url on experience site .inside Script tag
src="https://assets.adobedtm.com/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.min.js"
getting error Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'
'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

In order to resolve the CORS issue, you need to whitelist the URL that is being called. There are two places where you might want to add the URL as a whitelisted URL

Setup -> Trusted Sites
Setup -> CORS

Even after this, in case the error persists, URL needs to be whitelisted from the host side as well.
Read more about CORS here:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.extend_code_cors.htm&type=5
